# Библиотеки для Веб-интерфейса

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, веб-интерфейс

Слышал про библиотеку eel для питона. Библиотека довольно интересная, но мало ли есть более удобные и функциональные библиотеки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли такие?

Comment: cefpython..........

Comment: https://stackshare.io/stackups/eel-vs-electron

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, а Electron довольно соблазнительная тема. Можете, пожалуйста, ответ с примером и тд отправить?)

Comment: В интернете, к сожалению, не нахожу примеров(

Comment: https://www.electronjs.org/

Comment: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app

Comment: https://tproger.ru/translations/desktop-js-app-with-electron/

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/436466/

Comment: https://github.com/electron/electron

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/458502/

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/439946/

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/493540/

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=electron+js&oq=electron+js+&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i59j0l2j69i60l3.2837j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&client=ubuntu&hs=Gl1&ei=3Z10X5CPJY_1qwGfz7voBw&q=electron+js+habr&oq=electron+js+habr&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzICCAAyBggAEBYQHjoECAAQRzoECAAQQ1CGXli0ZWCHbGgAcAJ4AIABeIgBuwSSAQMwLjWYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjQ8drukpHsAhWP-ioKHZ_nDn0Q4dUDCA0&uact=5

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&client=ubuntu&hs=qSM&ei=ZZ50X4SWMeTJrgT4zq3wCw&q=electron+js+tutorial&oq=electron+js+t&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADoECAAQRzoGCAAQFhAeOggIABAWEAoQHjoFCAAQzQJQ7jJYkj5goUdoAnAFeACAAYEBiAHQApIBAzEuMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=psy-ab

Comment: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start

Comment: etc...hosts...шутка

Comment: https://overcoder.net/q/340906/python-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5-electron

Comment: https://pythondigest.ru/view/37152/

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=electron+js+python&oq=electron+js+python&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l6j69i61.4012j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: overflow of StackOverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

eel удобная и готовая к работе вещь.

Другие подобные вещи прийдется связывать почти вручную:

- electron python кто-то умудряется построить
- python-webkit (Cefpython3, webkit gtk, webkit qt)- классика, встраивание странички в окошко питона. Можно впихивать питоновские функции в контекст window или navigator и использовать из в яваскрипте.
- локальная служба + плагин в браузере и связь по апи
- сайт на локалхосте

Answer (score 2):

## Cefpython3

**[pypi](https://pypi.org/project/cefpython3/) | [github](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython)**

#### *Hello, World!*:

```
# Hello world example. Doesn't depend on any third party GUI framework.
# Tested with CEF Python v57.0+.

from cefpython3 import cefpython as cef
import platform
import sys


def main():
    check_versions()
    sys.excepthook = cef.ExceptHook  # To shutdown all CEF processes on error
    cef.Initialize()
    cef.CreateBrowserSync(url="https://www.google.com/",
                          window_title="Hello World!")
    cef.MessageLoop()
    cef.Shutdown()


def check_versions():
    ver = cef.GetVersion()
    print("[hello_world.py] CEF Python {ver}".format(ver=ver["version"]))
    print("[hello_world.py] Chromium {ver}".format(ver=ver["chrome_version"]))
    print("[hello_world.py] CEF {ver}".format(ver=ver["cef_version"]))
    print("[hello_world.py] Python {ver} {arch}".format(
           ver=platform.python_version(),
           arch=platform.architecture()[0]))
    assert cef.__version__ >= "57.0", "CEF Python v57.0+ required to run this"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

<sub>**(cef — Chromium embedded framework)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы ищете вот [это](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/desktop/desktop.html).
[ExtJS](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.0/) до 4й версии включительно была opensource.

По аналогам eel не слышал. Я бы использовал Electron.

Из хороших либ по интерфейсам актуальными на 2020 год остались:

- [PyGObject](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (бывший PyGTK),
- [PyQt](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro),
- [wxPython](https://www.wxpython.org/).

Comment: наоборот он ищет) не окошки в вэбе, а вэб в окошках.

Comment: чуть исправил ответ.

Comment: сложно найти пайтонову обёртку на яваскрипт